# H/w suggestions for 24 port PoE switch

Tags: switch

I am looking for a 24 port PoE(IEEE 802.3af) switch to power some Snom phones that I have. Please suggest some appliances. I just need basic L2 functions and wouldn't want to go for a expensive Cisco switch. Here are my requirements:

1) IEEE 802.3af PoE
2) 802.1q VLAN
3) Full-Duplex

I'd like a CLI also if possible, I've looked at Vyatta, but buying their 24 port appliance is way more expensive than a d-link or a netgear one. Thanks for your suggestions

Edit:
I've shortlisted the following(not had a look at HP so far)... I'd appreciate reviews if anybody is using any of these switches in production.

D-Link: DES1228P
Cisco: SRW224G4P, SFE2000P
Netgear: FS728TP

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: Have you considered mid-span devices? You can use them with your existing switches and replace either as your needs dictate.

Comment: budget is around 500$...

Answer (score 1):

i'm happy with hp procurve. take a look at [J9138A#ABB / 2520-24 POE](http://www.google.com/search?q=J9138A). i did not used this particular one [ i did not needed PoE ], but i never had problems with hp's managed / smart switches.

btw cli interface of hp devices is very similar to Cisco's ios.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using quite a lot (20-25, various clients) of Linksys/Cisco SLM224P (half-poe, only 12 ports PoE) and SRW224P to power Linksys phones, and only one had problems (2-3 lockups in a year).